# close sidr menu when user clicks link

Tags: sidr

I'm developing a site that uses the sidr menu. This site also uses modal windows to display content. when a user presses a menu item and it opens a modal window, the window opens below the sidr menu.

should I:

A. stack the modal window above the slidr menu so the entire contents can be seen? This might work as the toggle menu button is covered.

B. Force the menu to close so the modal window is not closed.

I thought changing the z-index of the modal window would work but I can't get it to load above the menu. the z-index of the menu is 999999. I tried 1,000,000 for the modal window, but it still loads below the menu.

what else can I try?